# Need Help Installing SuperMongo on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: make

I am trying to install SuperMongo on Ubuntu 18.04 and following this [guide](https://users.monash.edu.au/%7Ebburn/pdf/semtex_install.pdf). The guide for installing SuperMongo starts on page 6 of the link. When I run *make* I get the error shown below. I don't know what exactly the problem is so I am lost as to how to solve it. Can someone help?

error when running *make*:

```
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'lr0.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lr0.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/joseph/sm2_4_27/src/bison'
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'Bison' failed
make[1]: *** [Bison] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/joseph/sm2_4_27/src'
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'sm' failed
make: *** [sm] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a very similar issue on ubuntu 20.04 when installing supermongo. First, it seems that it is very important to use the latest distribution of SM which you can get from [www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/sm/distribution/sm-latest.tar.gz](http://www.astro.princeton.edu/%7Erhl/sm/distribution/sm-latest.tar.gz) (this is not a free program, so you will need a username and password for this step).

Next, you need to have 32-bit libraries enabled in ubuntu 20.04. Do something like

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt install libx11-dev
```

Then you install the sm. Just follow the instructions, in option I use macro size = 999999, float = double, char-length vector size = 156, and integers = LONG format.

Now the SM runs nicely in xgterm (usually as xgterm -sb which gives you also the scroll bar). Possibly you are an astronomer, so you will need iraf anyway, and xgterm is part of it. So obtain iraf from
github.com/iraf-community/iraf/blob/main/INSTALL.md
(be sure to move tar.gz to a suitable directory, e.g. /home/tomaz/iraf, before unpacking) then follow the instructions on the page above.

From the page https://github.com/iraf-community/ you can download also the X11iraf tools, which include xgterm.